# SQL - Select duplicates based on two columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I am using DB2 and am trying to count duplicate rows in a table called ML_MEASURE. What I define as a duplicate in this table, is a row containing the same DATETIME and TAG_NAME value. So I tried this below:

```
SELECT 
    DATETIME, 
    TAG_NAME, 
    COUNT(*) AS DUPLICATES
FROM 
    ML_MEASURE 
GROUP BY DATETIME, TAG_NAME 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The query doesn't fail, but I get an empty result, even though I now for a fact I have at least one duplicate, when I tried this query below I got the result correct for this specific tag_name and datetime:

```
SELECT
    DATETIME,
    TAG_NAME,
    COUNT(*) AS DUPLICATES
FROM
    ML_MEASURE
WHERE
    DATETIME='2018-03-23 15:09:30' AND
    TAG_NAME='HOG.613KU201'
GROUP BY
    DATETIME,
    TAG_NAME.
```

The result of the second query looked like this:

```
 DATETIME               TAG_NAME        DUPLICATES
 ---------------------  ------------    ----------
 2018-03-23 15:09:30.0  HOG.613KU201             3
```

What am I doing wrong in the first query?

*** UPDATE ***

My table is row organized, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: I don't know DB2, but from my "Oracle-ish" point of view - nothing's wrong with it, Should work just fine.

Comment: That is what I am thinking as well, but for some reason it is not working. the table is row organized, don't know if that makes any difference? @Littlefoot

Comment: I had a similar case recently, there was an APAR (bug fix), and the symptom varied with the precise statistics. So disclose your Db2-server *operating-system* and *fixpack/version* details....

Comment: I might guess that the tags have trailing spaces.  This can be accepted by comparison but still result in two rows for `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - ...but wouldn't that make the second query return 3 rows with 1 count each (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should get the same row back on the first query. If you had a `NOT ENFORCED TRUSTED` Primary Key or Unique constraint on those two columns, then the Optimizer would be within it's rights to trust the constraint and return you no rows. However from a quick test, I don't believe it does that for this query.
Do you have any indexes defined on the table?

(P.S. I assume you are not running the query from a shell prompt and redirecting the output to a file of the name `1`)

Comment: I actually just noticed that my primary keys are not enforced trusted. Is there another way to do this in that case? And yes I have indexes on this table, I have indexes on the DATETIME column

Comment: Using 'NOT ENFORCED TRUSTED' on constraints is high risk and invites the symptom that you experience.  Reconsider its use. Or add periodic verifications.

Comment: Primary Key constraints can't be marked as `NOT TRUSTED` , that only applies to FKs constraints. Also `DISABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION` only applies to FK or Check constraints.  For `NOT ENFORCED` PKs, if you don't want the optimizer to trust them, your only option (I believe) is to drop the constraint, or to enforce it (i.e. recreate the PK as `ENFORCED`.   Can I ask what version of Db2 you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DATETIME, TAG_NAME, COUNT(*) AS DUPLICATES
    FROM ML_MEASURE 
    GROUP BY DATETIME, TAG_NAME 
) WHERE DUPLICATES > 1
```